# libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode@LIBUDEV_183 when cross-building Qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1 for BeagleBone Black

Tags: qt, g++, qt5, beagleboneblack

I am new to using Qt (and building it).
I have searched on the web and landed at multiple ways of cross-building the Qt src for Beaglebone Black, of multiple versions, but haven't been successful to build any of those.

I am following the guide from one of the GitHub pages [here](https://github.com/K3tan/BBB_QT5_guide/blob/master/QtFullGuide.pdf).

The configure and make commands worked fine and didn't give any errors (just some warnings).
But when I tried "make install", the build continued until I was bombarded with a bunch of errors for with the 'libQt5SerialPort.so.5' and fails ultimately with 'Error 1' and 'Error 2'.

Here's the terminal log which give the undefined reference errors:

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialbus/src/tools/canbusutil'
/home/yash/BBB/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/yash/BBB/sysroot -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtbase/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib -o ../../../bin/canbusutil .obj/main.o .obj/readtask.o .obj/canbusutil.o .obj/sigtermhandler.o .obj/moc_readtask.o .obj/moc_canbusutil.o .obj/moc_sigtermhandler.o   /home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialbus/lib/libQt5SerialBus.so /home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtbase/lib/libQt5Core.so -lpthread  -lrt -lpthread -ldl
```

```
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_driver@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysname@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_property_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode@LIBUDEV_183'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile:99: ../../../bin/canbusutil] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialbus/src/tools/canbusutil'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:59: sub-canbusutil-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialbus/src/tools'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:112: sub-tools-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialbus/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:61: sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/BBB/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtserialbus'
make: *** [Makefile:178: module-qtserialbus-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

I have tried clean building the same multiple times, but always faced the same issue.

Can someone please help with figuring out what is going wrong here?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: sudo make install

Comment: @DeFunct, that didnt work and continued to give the same errors, even for a clean build.

Comment: Are you using a prebuilt distro, Buildroot, or Yocto? Your toolchain is outdated (severely). Also, try the forum.beagleboard.org site online. I noticed there are many people interested in compiling and Qt in general that will be able to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone trying to build Qt for cross-compilation for BeagleBone Black, following this [guide](https://github.com/K3tan/BBB_QT5_guide) properly would work.

**PS:** It should be kept in mind to download qtcreator with a version equivalent to or older than the qt-source being built.

Comment: Author already referenced to this link.

Answer (score 0):

I think using an updated image and the qt5 libs. available would be easier for you.

For instance, when you get the image and write it to SD Card from https://forum.beagleboard.org/t/debian-11-x-bullseye-monthly-snapshots/31280 , you can then use this command:

`apt search qt5`

That will allow you to search for all that is available from qt5 in the Debian Buster or Bullseye Distro(s).

Enjoy. Oh...Bullseye uses `apt search` while Buster uses `apt-cache search`.

I have been researching a bit more:

1. https://doc.qt.io/embedded.html
2. https://doc.qt.io/QtForMCUs-2.1/qtul-supported-platforms.html#other-target-boards

The idea behind cmake, make, installing on the BBB is far beyond what we can discuss on this forum. I cannot pinpoint the issue from the info. given thus far.

If and when you find time, please visit forum.beagleboard.org and they have many people that are knowledgeable on the BBB on that site.

Comment: but isn't this applicable for building and compilings Qt apps natively on the BBB? I want to build a cross-compiling environment on my Ubuntu machine and build Qt applications using Qt creator on the host machine and then deploy to run on the BBB.

Comment: The reason I said what I said is that Qt5 takes up a lot of memory when compiling it from source and the libraries already available on the Debian Bullseye Distro has many available Qt5 libs. for use. You can use a lot of the already compiled Distro libs. for building Qt5 applications natively or cross-compile them to the BBB with sftp or another way.